# Submitting a Form on Another Page

Tags: javascript, iframe, authentication

We subscribe to a number of online databases/newspapers/etc. that students can use for research. However, the current system is quite cumbersome. The user has to:

1. Navigate to the school's webpage.
2. Sign in with their school username

   - They are then brought to a list of the database credentials & links.
3. Clicks on a database link.
4. Enters the credentials into the database log-in page (hosted by another company).

Everyone uses the same credentials, but each database has its own username/password.

What I am trying to do is create a system where step 4 is removed. That is, the student signs in with their school credentials and clicks on a database link. They are then *automatically* signed into the database.

So... how would I go about implementing this?

My first thought was to create a full-window iframe. The iframe displays the database, but the actual page is hosted on the school server. Then the actual page enters the credentials and submits the form through javascript.

But is this not possible (b/c XSS)? Should I simulate a POST request to the database, and then return to the user? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to update this question with my solution—

While what I wanted to do (entering data into a form & automatically submitting it) wasn't possible due to XSS restrictions, I did come up with a similar idea.

What I ended up doing is **duplicating** the login form onto our local server, but changing the `action` attribute.

So I copied this from the database's login page:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit-button">
</form>
```

and changed it to this:

```
<form action="http://database.example.com/Authentication/LogOn" method="post">
    <input id="username" name="username" type="hidden" value="OUR_USERNAME">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="hidden" value="OUR_PASSWORD">
    <input type="submit" value="Auto Login" class="submit-button">
</form>
```

(this was just a test; on the actual service, javascript automatically submits the form upon page load; the form is `hidden` so the user sees nothing.).

So now, instead of submitting the form to a local page, it is submitted to a remote page... I never knew you could do this, but it works like a charm. I haven't yet had any problems with it [tested in Chrome & Firefox], but it *might* be able to cause problems in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out SAML (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language), which seems predestined for your use case (as long as the DB-hosting company can implement it on their side, too).

Update: In case SAML does not work, I guess you'd need to create a POST request from the user's browser to the database login page that already contains the login details. If the DB login mechanism needs a username and a password as arguments (which is likely), this isn't a very secure process, though, as the password will be readable in the source code by the user.

Comment: doubt they'll do that just for one school... no other way to do it just on our end? (either with school-server-side scripting or client-side js?)